# pair<int,int> pair as key of unordered_map issue

Tags: c++, unordered-map, std-pair

My code:

```
 typedef pair<int,int> Pair
  tr1::unordered_map<Pair,bool> h;
  h.insert(make_pair(Pair(0,0),true));
```

Erorr

```
 undefined reference to `std::tr1::hash<std::pair<int, int> >::operator()(std::pair<int, int>) const'
```

Something I need to fix?

thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This happens because there is no specialization for `std::tr1::hash<Key>` with `Key = std::pair<int, int>`.
You must to specialize `std::tr1::hash<Key>` with `Key = std::pair<int, int>` before declaring `tr1::unordered_map<Pair,bool> h;`.
This happens because `std` don't know how to hash a `pair<int, int>`.

Following there is a example of how to specialize `std::tr1::hash<>`

```
template <>
struct std::tr1::hash<std::pair<int, int> > {
public:
        size_t operator()(std::pair<int, int> x) const throw() {
             size_t h = SOMETHING;//something with x   
             return h;
        }
};
```

Comment: Which is unfortunate, because if I specialize it for use in my library, and you specialize it for use in your library, and our definitions aren't identical, then when our libraries are linked together we get undefined behavior. `std::tr1::hash` is a bit under-specced, it's better if possible to specify a custom Hash class to the `unordered_map` instead, as the third template parameter.

Comment: No, you can gain quite a lot without any pain, much more than with.

Comment: @Murilo: if it ain't hurting, it ain't C++.

Comment: @Steven :). But think about how to make a generic hash function for all possible types. In Java also, we have to override `hashCode()` for HashTables working with non-trivial types. +1 for your first comment because is a true but necessary evil.

Comment: @Murilo: It's hardly necessary. Standard types can easily have standard, unspecified hashes. It's only necessary for non-standard types, and even that's arguable.

Comment: @Murilo: but `std::pair` is a library class, so IMO the library should provide a hashcode (subject of course to the contained types having hashcodes). Java provides a hashcode for containers, as does Python for its built-in tuple type (but not for mutable containers, since Python doesn't allow mutable hash keys). C++0x has hashcodes for at least some containers, haven't checked if it's all of them. Looks to me like it has them for vector but not pair or tuple, which if true is odd, I think.

Comment: `std::pair` is a templated type. Unlike Java with Generics for example `std::pair<int, int>` is one type different from `std::pair<int, double>` (for example an `ArrayList<Integer>` is the same type of `ArrayList<String>` in Java). Each specialization generates code for differents types and is because of that, I think, is not possible to do a generic hash function.

Comment: @Murilo: of course it's possible: `template <typename T, U> struct hash<pair<T,U> > { size_t operator() { return hash<T>()(first) ^ hash<U>()(second); }};`. This provides a valid hashcode for `pair<T,U>` provided that the hashcodes for T and U are valid. As I say, C++0x has generic hashes for vector, and so do Java and Python for collections. So I don't understand why generic hash for pair is missing in TR1, let alone C++0x.

Comment: Bah, I failed to type the parameter to operator(), but the point is that for any container or container-like entity, if you have decent hashcodes for the elements you can define a decent hashcode for the whole thing provided that `operator==` does element-wise comparison.

Comment: @Murilo: Sure, that isn't a great hashcode, a better one would be hash(first)*31 + hash(second), or whatever you'd use for a 2-character string. You *don't* have to hash all kinds of elements, the template naturally means that if the contents have a hashcode then the pair does too. If the contents don't have a (useful) hashcode then don't try to hash the pair either. This is exactly the situation that pertains in Java, I don't see any problem with it.

Comment: @Steve: Ok, you are right. Would be good if this appears in the next standard.

Comment: I'm compiling with g++ 4.7.3 on ubuntu.  Pasting the code in the answer, I get an error: specialization of template<class_Tp> std::tr1::hash in a different namespace.  So i wrap the code in namespace std {  namespace tr1 //// code block /// } }.  Then i get an error: explicit specialization of non-template std::tr1<anonymous struct>

Answer (score 6):

Unordered Map does not contain a hash function for a pair, So if we want to hash a pair then we have to explicitly provide it with a hash function that can hash a pair.

If we want to use pair as a key to unordered_map, there are 2 ways to do it :

1. Define specializaion for std::hash

```
typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> pair;

struct pair_hash
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2> &pair) const
    {
        return std::hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ std::hash<T2>()(pair.second);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<pair,int,pair_hash> unordered_map =
    {
        {{"C++", "C++11"}, 2011},
        {{"C++", "C++14"}, 2014},
        {{"C++", "C++17"}, 2017},
        {{"Java", "Java 7"}, 2011},
        {{"Java", "Java 8"}, 2014},
        {{"Java", "Java 9"}, 2017}
    };

    for (auto const &entry: unordered_map)
    {
        auto key_pair = entry.first;
        std::cout << "{" << key_pair.first << "," << key_pair.second << "}, "
                  << entry.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

2. Using Boost Library
   Another good way is to use boost::hash from Boost.functional which can be used to hash integers,floats,pointers,strings,arrays,pairs and theh STL containers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> pair;

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<pair,int,boost::hash<pair>> unordered_map =
    {
        {{"C++", "C++11"}, 2011},
        {{"C++", "C++14"}, 2014},
        {{"C++", "C++17"}, 2017},
        {{"Java", "Java 7"}, 2011},
        {{"Java", "Java 8"}, 2014},
        {{"Java", "Java 9"}, 2017}
    };

    for (auto const &entry: unordered_map)
    {
        auto key_pair = entry.first;
        std::cout << "{" << key_pair.first << "," << key_pair.second << "}, "
                  << entry.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue:

```
unordered_map <pair<x, y>, z> m1;
```

A few workarounds are:

```
unordered_map <stringxy, z> m1;
// the first and second of the pair merged to a string
//   though string parsing may be required, looks same complexity overall

unordered_multimap <x, pair<y, z>> m1;
// second of the pair of the key went into value.  
//   time complexity slightly increases

deque<deque<x>> d1;
// here x & y are of same type, z is stored as: d1[x][y] = z
//   space required is x * y, however time complexity is O(1)
```

Comment: Is `unordered_multimap <x, pair<y, z>> m1;` sufficient for inserting two pairs (x,y) such that x is the same and y is different? How would the hash function know to use y if it's in the value section?

Comment: I really want to help, but I lost the context of the above details. Did the comments, already given above, help at all?