# Admissible type of key in map v.s. unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I understand that `unordered_map<T, int>` would be more efficient when retrieving a value from the key O(1), than `map<T, int>` would be O(lg n) regarding the performance.

However, I found that `unordered_map<T, int>` does not support as many types as `map<T, int>` does.

For instance, `map<pair<int, int>, int>` is OK, but `unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int>` is not.

I am wondering is there any underlying difficulty for this? If the performance is concerned, what data structure could I use to get a hashtable of key-type pair with O(1) performance.

Comment: It isn't clear if you're asking why it doesn't work out of the box, or want to know how to make it work. The answers so far address the latter.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Very good point. I updated to try to address the first question.

Comment: @merlin2011 Well, I would have interpreted as asking "why is `std::hash` not specialized for `std:pair<T, T>` where `T` is a type for which `std::hash` *is* specialized :-)

Comment: This is a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7222201/390913

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does not work out of the box is because the type `pair<T,T>` does not define a hash function and `unordered_map` is essentially a hash map, so its keys *must be hashable*.

There is nothing fundamentally wrong with `unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int>`. The problem is that you need to provide a **hash function** and a **comparison function** for equality.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870467/391161) for your specific case of `<pair,pair>` as key and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17017281/391161) for more details on the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom hash function:

```
#include <unordered_map>

typedef std::pair<int,int> int_pair;
class MyHashFunc {
    std::hash<int> int_hash_func;
    public:
        long operator()(const int_pair &k) const{

            return (int_hash_func(k.first) << 16) + (int_hash_func(k.second));
        }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<int_pair, int, MyHashFunc> m;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can provide a way to generate a hash from `pair<int, int>`, then you can use it.

Example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

struct IntPairHash
{
   size_t operator()(pair<int, int> const& p)
   {
      // If you have a 64 bit platform where sizeof(size_t) == 64
      // and sizeof(int) == 32, you can use:
      size_t h = p.second;
      h <<= 32;
      h += p.first;
      return h;

      // For other platforms, a more different approach to come up with
      // a hash value for p must be devised.
   }
};

void foo()
{
   unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int, IntPairHash> a;
}
```

Comment: `h <<= 32;` - if `sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(int)` you've just thrown away `p.second` completely... better to `xor` with say `(h << 1) ^ (h >> 1)` though for `sizeof(size_t) == 2 * sizeof(int)` it would leave the high order bits 0, that's less likely to be important when modded/anded into a hash table bucket count.

Comment: @TonyD Point well made. I updated my answer to add that caveat.