# Inserting into unordered_map<pair<int,int>, int> throwing compiler errors

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, unordered-map

Is there anything semantically wrong with the following code?:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  unordered_map<pair<int,int>, int> M;  // <--- many compiler errors here
  pair<int,int> p = make_pair(5,4);

  M[p] = 3;
}
```

I'm getting a bunch of compiler errors, but to me it seems like it should work fine (as it does if I just use an `int` as the key of the `unordered_map`). Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870437/pairint-int-pair-as-key-of-unordered-map-issue

Comment: Maybe if you posted the compiler errors that might help people to help you?

Answer (score 1):

You are getting lot of compiler error at following [line](http://ideone.com/A6iUwb):

```
unordered_map<pair<int,int>, int> M;
```

That's because you are defining `pair<int, int>` as key of the `unordered_map` & there is **no implicit `hash`** for `pair<int, int>` (though `operator==` is present).
Such errors will occur even when you give some dummy `class X` as its key, if it doesn't have `hash` &/or `operator==`.

In general, while declaring an `unordered_map`'s key, below functions should be accessible by the "key":

```
template <class Key,
          class T,
          class Hash = hash<Key>,  // implement if missing
          class Pred = equal_to<Key>,  // implement if missing
          class Alloc = allocator<pair<const Key,T>>
          >
class unordered_map;
```

In case of `int`, the default `hash` & `operator==` imply; hence no error.

Comment: `pair` does define [`operator==`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) so the OP only needs to define a hash. One way to do that would be to use `boost::hash_combine` to combine hashes from the two ints in the pair.