# Hash for a std::pair, for use in an unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary, hashmap, unordered-map, std-pair

When doing

```
unordered_map<pair<unsigned int, unsigned int>, unsigned int> m;
```

we get

> Error C2338: The C++ Standard doesn't provide a hash for this type.

**Is there a built-in way to define a hash for a `std::pair` of `int` or do we need to define it manually?** (in this case, the hash could be just *(the bytes of first item)(the bytes of second item of the pair)* glued together).

Note: I'm using VC++ 2013.

Note2: the answer to [pair<int,int> pair as key of unordered_map issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870437/pairint-int-pair-as-key-of-unordered-map-issue) doesn't clearly address the question of how to actually create the hash with two `int`s, as detailed here.

Comment: If you are asking is it part of the C++ Standard, then no.

Comment: There is no "built-in way"; however you are free to define and implement your own specialization.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use boost, rolling your own shouldn't be too hard.
static_assert added to ensure the assumption that 2 ints fit into 1 size_t is maintained.

```
using IntPair = std::pair<int, int>;

struct IntPairHash {
    static_assert(sizeof(int) * 2 == sizeof(size_t));

    size_t operator()(IntPair p) const noexcept {
        return size_t(p.first) << 32 | p.second;
    }
};

std::unordered_map<IntPair, int, IntPairHash> myMap;
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this answer. It's not *required* to specialize `std::hash`; that's just an option.

Comment: In fact, I would recommend to avoid specializing std::hash in a case like this one because it affects a larger scope of code than just your one use-case.  Don't specialize std::hash  when you're a CLIENT of a user-defined type that you want to hash, but when you are the PROVIDER of a type, and you want everyone to use a sensible hash function for your type.  Specializing for std::hash on a _standard_ type increases the chance to conflict with someone else's specialization and potentially violate the ODR.

Comment: If `p.second` is negative and being implicitly casted to size_t, its binary representation may be all 1 at the high 32 bits, thus masking `p.first`, which may cause a conflict. So it may be necessary to do something like `size_t(p.second) & 0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Very good point @hakula.  The next issue is assuming the size of int.  I put a static_assert that 2 ints fit in a size_t, but it might be better to use a fixed size integer (`std::int32_t`, etc) to be sure it fits.  The mask depends on the int being 4 bytes.  We could alternate cast it to std::uint32_t (again assuming we know the size) before ANDing it.