# Make unordered set of struct objects

Tags: c++, struct, set

I've got a `struct` type of which I'd like to make an unordered set.  Here's my MRE:

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Point {
    unsigned int x;
    unsigned int y;

    Point(unsigned int x_value, unsigned int y_value)
    {
        x = x_value;
        y = y_value;
    }

    Point(const Point &p)
    {
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
    }

    bool operator<(const Point &p) const
    {
        return x < p.x || ( x == p.x && y < p.y);
    }
} Point;

int main() {
    unordered_set<Point> pset;

    pset.insert(Point(1, 2));

    return 0;
}
```

However, when I try to compile (using g++ for C++20), I get a **long** list of errors beginning with

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:28:26: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() [with _Value = Point; _Hash = std::hash<Point>; _Pred = std::equal_to<Point>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Point>]
   28 |     unordered_set<Point> pset;
      |                          ^~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/unordered_set:47,
from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/unordered_set.h:135:7: note: ‘std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() [with _Value = Point; _Hash = std::hash<Point>; _Pred = std::equal_to<Point>; _Alloc = std::allocator<Point>]’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
  135 |       unordered_set() = default;
```

Comment: An `std::unordered_set` does not use `operator <` to determine where to place an element.  It uses a hash of the key type.  You want `std::set` if your intent is to store the items using a strict-weak-ordering of the key.  So you need to clarify whether you want a hash set (unordered_set) or a "regular" set.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Yes, I want an unordered set.  I've updated my question.

Comment: small nit - you don't need the copy constructor. The default copy constructor should suffice and be equivalent.

Comment: If you aliased your `Point` class to be `std::pair<unsigned, unsigned>`, then the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45395071/hash-for-a-stdpair-for-use-in-an-unordered-map) can also help in creating the hash function.  You could also copy the hash function from that answer and use it for `Point` if you don't want to change `Point` to a `std::pair`.